# Getting this error while deploying angular app on ec2 by cicd

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cicd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNfRp.png)
getting this error

my buildspec.yml is ---
version: 0.2
phases:
install:
runtime-versions:
nodejs: 16
commands:
- echo "installing nodejs..."
- curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.5/install.sh
| bash
- apt-get install -y nodejs
pre_build:
commands:
- echo installing dependencies...
- npm install -g @angular/cli
- npm install
build:
commands:
- ng build --prod || exit 0
post_build:
commands:
- mkdir -p ./dist/myapp2
- mv appspec.yml ./dist/myapp2
- mv scripts ./dist/myapp2
artifacts:
files:
- "**/*"
base-directory: dist/myapp2

and appspec.yml is
version: 1.0
os: linux
files:

- source: /
  destination: /var/www/html/
  hooks:
  BeforeInstall:

  - location: scripts/remove_root_dir
    timeout: 900
    runas: root
    ApplicationStart:
  - location: scripts/install_dependencies
    timeout: 300
    runas: root
  - location: scripts/start_server
    timeout: 300
    runas: root

## BeforeInstall:

## - location: scripts/install_dependencies

## timeout: 300

## runas: root

## - location: scripts/start_server

## timeout: 300

## runas: root

ApplicationStop:
- location: scripts/stop_server
timeout: 300
runas: root